# systemd-journald fails to start on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, systemd, journald

Since a week ago, journald doesn't finish starting anymore. When booting up, it starts up and logs the boot messages and a few other service startup logs, and then abruptly shuts down when starting `Switch Root`:

```
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local systemd-journal[96]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 391.1M, trying to leave 586.7M free of 3.8G available → current limit 391.1M).
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local systemd-journal[96]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 391.1M, trying to leave 586.7M free of 3.8G available → current limit 391.1M).
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016
Mar 18 05:22:56 playground1.local kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8 console=ttyS0 systemd.debug

...

Mar 18 05:22:57 playground1.local systemd[1]: Reached target Switch Root.
Mar 18 05:22:57 playground1.local systemd[1]: Starting Switch Root.
Mar 18 05:22:57 playground1.local systemd[1]: Starting Switch Root...
Mar 18 05:22:57 playground1.local systemd[1]: Switching root.
Mar 18 05:22:57 playground1.local systemd-journal[96]: Journal stopped
```

If I try to start it manually, it fails quickly:

```
[root@playground1 ~]# systemctl start systemd-journald.service
Job for systemd-journald.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status systemd-journald.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@playground1 ~]# systemctl status systemd-journald.service
● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2016-03-18 16:38:21 EDT; 21s ago
    Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
          man:journald.conf(5)
  Process: 3404 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 3404 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Status: "Shutting down..."
[root@playground1 ~]#
```

`journalctl -xe` prints the boot logs, when manually starting the service it doesn't get to actually write anything to the journal. If I delete the journal file, it doesn't get created.

Running `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald` manually kind of works, meaning that the process is started, and `journalctl` contains the journald startup logs, but nothing else is actually logged afterwards.

`systemd-journald.socket` also seems to fail to load, and it might be the cause of the failure, but I don't see anything in the logs about it:

```
[root@playground1 systemd]# systemctl status systemd-journald.socket
● systemd-journald.socket - Journal Socket
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.socket; static; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: service-failed-permanent) since Fri 2016-03-18 16:46:24 EDT; 4min 8s ago
    Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
          man:journald.conf(5)
  Listen: /run/systemd/journal/stdout (Stream)
          /run/systemd/journal/socket (Datagram)
          /dev/log (Datagram)
```

I don't think it's related to SELinux, since the only thing that's denied is reading `machine-id`, which shouldn't be a showstopper. However, one weird thing that I did notice in the audit logs is that the service appears to be starting twice?

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1458334641.993:330): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=3689 comm="systemd-journal" name="machine-id" dev="dm-0" ino=67109045 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1458334641.993:330): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fbc38ebf08f a1=80100 a2=7ffeb87c80bf a3=3 items=0 ppid=1 pid=3689 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="systemd-journal" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald" subj=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1458334642.002:331): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-journald comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1458334642.002:332): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-journald comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1458334642.002:333): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-journald comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

See the two `SERVICE_START` messages, one with `res=failed` and one with `res=success`.

Google tells me that nobody else had this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AVC indicates that the file being read doesn't have an SELinux label.

This can happen if SELinux was disabled when the file was created, or if it is created on a filesystem that isn't SELinux-capable (e.g. vfat).

If someone had disabled and re-enabed SELinux, then you should be able to fix the problem (and possibly many others) by relabeling the filesystem. You can do this online with:

```
restorecon -r /
```

If the filesystem on which the file resides doesn't support SELinux, then you need to replace it with a filesystem that does support SELinux, and then relabel.

Comment: `restorecon -r /` did indeed fix it, but the error seems to have been someplace else, since relabeling only `/dev/dm-0`, which was reported in the audit log, didn't fix it, neither did relabeling all of `/dev`.

Comment: The particular file being complained about appears to have been `/etc/machine-id`. There were probably others unlabeled as well.